# Ionic Editing item data in an ngFor array

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

So I have a `list.html` and `list.ts` file

This is my list using `*ngFor`

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.description}}</p>
        <p>{{item.amount}}</p>
        <p>{{item.uniqueID}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And in `lists.ts` I have a function that gets new data on events,

```
this.events.on('dataAvailable', (data) => {

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

        this.ngZone.run(() => {

          this.items.push({
            name: data[0].name,
            description: data[0].description,
            amount: data[0].amount,
            uniqueID: data[0].uniqueID
          });  

        });

      }

});
```

This works fine and new data is added in the list every time 
the event fires. However the event can contain data for an already
existing item in an array.

I understand that I can find the `index` of the already existing item
in `items` and update the data that way, however I need a more direct
approach on editing existing data, probably by the `uniqueID`.

Help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map the array to the `uniqueID` to see if the new item already exists, then decide what to do based on the index:

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {
  let index = this.items.map(x => x.uniqueID).indexOf(data[0].uniqueID);
  let newItem = {
    name: data[0].name,
    description: data[0].description,
    amount: data[0].amount,
    uniqueID: data[0].uniqueID
  }
  if (index !== -1) {
    this.items.push(newItem);
  } else {
    this.items[index] = newItem;
  }
});
```